# .resx File Size Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am working in Visual Studio 2010, on a fairly beefy machine. I have a solution with a few different projects under it like so

```
Solution
  Activations
  DatabaseManager
  Library
  VideoResources
  WindowsNewUI <--- start up project
```

In video Resources I have one .resx file in which I have placed about 700mb of compressed videos. When I build this project by itself, the build succeeds. Then I hit f5 to run my new UI and I am given this error.

Error   1   Unexpected error writing metadata to file VideoResources.dll -- 'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

I have done some digging and it seems to be a ram issue. I have tried the /3gb fix by editing the .ini file, but this does not solve the problem.

My question is what the heck am I doing wrong here, I know that 700mb is a lot of video, but there is no reason that that specif project should build, but then fail the rest of my project, is something else going on here? Does the access modifier of that projects resource file mater? How can I resolve this issue?

Also if I place about half of my video files in the .resx then everything works just fine.

Comment: Can't you just split your videos into multiple resource files. I would be suprised if the access modifier has anything to do with it. I'm guessing there's a reference behind the scenes to these resource dlls that cannot handle one specific dll being that large.

Comment: Yes this is something else I am willing to try; but I wanted to avoid having TONS of .resx files, and it would be more difficult to access the files pragmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource file infrastructure is probably not designed to scale to these file sizes. Remember that every operation in a resx file happens in memory, and you're using a garbage-collected language.

Why not just store the video(s) in the filesystem and read them as needed?

Comment: Im assuming he's doing this to cut the access time of each video. Since it's all going to be in memory it will be a lot faster to the end user rather than loading each one from the filesystem at the time of use.

Comment: That might have made sense 20 years ago.

Comment: but unless the user is using SSD wouldn't that still apply? hd's have come a long way over the years in regards to space but not so much in read speeds with the exception of SSDs which still dont seem to be widely used yet at this point.

Comment: Actually I am doing it because I wanted to prevent users from being able to access the videos directly; The videos should only be available if an upgrade is purchased. It did not seem to be a good solution to change the extension, as some of the more ingenious user could simple change the file extension back to see the videos.

Comment: @Siegeon Wouldn't it be better to store the videos as files with some kind of encryption?

Comment: @kprobst - Sure maybe? Would the decode fast? I sort of thought that that is what a .resx file did.

Comment: You could remove the encryption and then stream them. I'm not sure how much security you need here, but you should know that if you stored something in a resx file then I can probably get to it anyway, unless it's encrypted or obfuscated somehow. So you still need to protect them; might as well find a solution that involves the filesystem and eliminates the issues with the resource manager, which you won't be able to get around anyway.

Comment: Its easy as pie to move around the resource manager, especially you create types that mach the file names. I don't need the videos super locked down, if someone was able to retrieve the individual files from the .dll then I figure they should just have the videos. All that aside, I will looking to encrypting the file and loading them directly from file, rather then from the .resx.

Comment: Sorry I didnt see the rest of this conversation before I posted my answer but I agree with Kprobst. Here is a decent code sample of an encryption class that I found while taking a quick look around. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/DotNetCrypto.aspx

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion would be to not store the video in any type of embedded resource.  Thats going to cause your app to us a ton of memory while it is running.  I would suggest that you instead just leave the files on disk and load them from there. This would also fix your problem.

Comment: The only issue here is protecting the videos. I was using the .resx method to prevent users from accessing the files directly.

Comment: @Siegeon: There are much more effective ways to do that.